# DDD Repository Awareness of Other Repositories

Tags: language-agnostic, architecture, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Is it generally acceptable that one repository can access another repository?  Specifically in this case, I have one aggregate root that uses another aggregate root to determine what entities to add.  It falls along the lines of an Item/Item Type relationship.  The reason that the Item Type is an aggregate root is that they are separately maintainable within a management tool outside of the scope of any single Item.

If it does matter, I am only creating my repository instances through a repository factory implementation, so I am not directly creating it by the concrete class name.  At no time is the aggregate aware of the repository.

**Edit - More information:**

The specific implementation is that we can attach images to a document.  Not only can we manage the images on the document, but there are different types of images (types being defined as how it is implemented, as opposed to an extension, for example).  The document aggregate is one of a few types of other objects in the system that use these images and they do not all use the same types.  While we do attach rules in the domain services, this is more specifically geared towards building the document aggregate.  When building the aggregate we have five images of a specific type, and one each of two other types.  We pull these individually because they are stored in separate lists in the aggregate.  The validation is not the issue, but limiting what type of images are being evaluated when assembling the document.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187667/calling-a-repository-from-a-repository

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it boils down to what your trying to do. If it's a sort of validation step (e.g. remove all items that have item types that have expired)  you could argue it belongs in a service layer or specification. From the language you use (i.e. "determine what entities to add") it seems to suggest the latter, though it's hard to say without more details.

I guess from a certain point of view there's no real reason why you can't (I'm by no means a super DDD purest), especially since an Item and its type could be viewed as an aggregate root and it's only the implementation detail that you need to provide a management console that's prevent.

From another point of view it does seem to suggest that there's a blurring between your aggregate roots that could suggest two different contexts are at work. For instance, one could argue that a management tool forms a separate bounded context to your main application and therefore the case for the Item type being an aggregate root does not really apply. e.g. The management tool might only ever be concerned with Item Types (and never items) while your main application might view item types as more of a value object than an entity.

**Update**

As you mention assembling the document this seems like the responsibility of a factory class that can correctly assemble a valid entity (the factory can use the image type repository). A repository should (in my eyes) expose querying and adding operations, not the logic to configure entities (except maybe rehydrating from persistence).

Comment: Added additional information.  It is not validation related, but assembly related.  We are trying to "bucket" certain types of images into different entity groups within the aggregate.  With the additional information, for example, there might be five "Example Images" and a "Summary Image".  They are all an "Image", but vary by their "Image Type".  The "Image Type" is used when assembling the document to make sure that the correct images are being gathered from the underlying data source.

Comment: Well if it concerns the way the aggregate is assembled I would say that the responsibility should fall to a factory? The factory would have knowledge of how the image types are stored and how to bucket the images. You'd then persist the aggregate via the repository

Comment: Yes, I think that is the best way to do it.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could the factory you mention also be described as a Service? I tend to find myself always trying to fit domain objects into the categories I've been reading about within DDD so the word Factory makes sense in terms of pattern but would that factory generally be referred to as a service for DDD purposes?

Answer (score 1):

It does not follow the principles of DDD to have one repository using another repository. If you need data from one aggregate root to perform some action on another aggregate root, you can retrieve the first root (in the application service layer or possibly in a domain service) and then pass that data into the public api of the dependent aggregate root, or in the case of aggregate root creation where a separate factory is being used, into the factory's public api.

An aggregate root defines a transactional boundary, where the data within it should remain *transactionally consisten*t. This expectation of transactional consistency should not extend to anything outside that boundary. If you have a repository dependent on another respository then you have the state of one aggregate being transactionally dependent on the state another aggregate, which means neither of these 'aggregate roots' are actually aggregate roots.

Furthermore, if you need changes to state of one aggregate to effect the state of another aggregate, you should use domain events for this, which enforce *eventual consistency* between the roots.